# default export does not get called multiple times when imported from different files

Tags: typescript

Maybe I'm understanding this wrong.  Lets say I have the following file in TypeScript

```
// client.ts
const getClient = () => {
  console.log("being called");
  return {name: "abcd"}
};

export default getClient();

// consumer1.ts
import getClient from './client.ts'

// consumer2.ts
import getClient from './client.ts'
```

Now when I run this I expect `being called` to be written twice to the console, but instead I see only 1 call.  How can this be and what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. If you don't import it anywhere it will still execute. You are executing a function and exporting the result. You can import it later as many times as you wish. It will execute only once.

Breaking it down to sub-modules makes no difference in this case. Consider this jsfiddle: 
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xco2db9a/2/)

What you are probably expecting is to do this:

```
const getClient = () => {
  console.log("being called");
  return {
    name: "abcd"
  }
};

export default getClient
--

import getClient from './client.ts'
const clientModule = getClient()

import getClient from './client.ts'
const clientModule = getClient()
```

Comment: "It will execute only once", How is this possible, does the engine run some optimisation ?